# How can I paste the IPython output in IPython?

Tags: ipython, paste

The question's title tells it; I'm reading a book and I'd like to try the code on the fly using IPython but all the code is structured like this:

```
right = DataFrame({'key1': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar'],
....: 'key2': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two'],
....: 'rval': [4, 5, 6, 7]})
```

I'd like to copy it directly from the book inside the terminal but even using %paste I receive an Invalid Syntax error. I could use %cpaste but for longer inputs it is kind of frustrating.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It seems that %paste only detects and strips pure python's continuation prompt `... `, but not ipython's `....: `. So changing the prompts to `...` would work. But that's probably not an option for you.

Comment: Exactly, because the code is from a book not from my prompt

Comment: IPython should be able to handle this. The docs say IPython session code can be pasted since version 1. Perhaps it's a regression that hasn't been noticed (bug). http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/interactive/reference.html?#pasting-of-code-starting-with-python-or-ipython-prompts

Comment: Your problem is that you want to remove the dots ?

Comment: @jeanrjc: I don't think so - the problem is that ipython's paste magic claims to be able to handle ipython prompts, but apparently that is not the case. It's probably a good idea to file an issue at ipython's issue tracker: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues

Comment: This only appears to be the case for 1.2. IPython 2.1 handles IPython prompts just fine.

Comment: My version is the 2.1.0, Python 3.3.5, Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

So it should work, but you need to be sure that when pasting the `....:` are well aligned. Meaning that you need to copy carefully.

The following should work for instance :

```
right = DataFrame({'key1': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar'],
   ....: 'key2': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two'],
   ....: 'rval': [4, 5, 6, 7]})
```

Or this one too (where we see the alignment with the semi column of `In []:` :

```
In [68]: a = [1,
   ....: 2,
   ....: 3]
```

My guess that if you cannot copy better than you did, is that the book did a bad formatting when pasting. If so, you still can open a basic text editor and find and replace `....:` with nothing.

Instead of opening an issue, it should be more probably related to a feature of the `%paste` function which implement something that deals with bad indentation, but then it starts being messy, IMO.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As you pointed out your examples work fine, the problem is that while copy pasting from the book it doesn't preserve the spaces before ....: and so the indentation is destroyed. I think though that IPython should be able to handle this

Comment: Maybe because it's a pdf. What book is it ?

Comment: I know, but then the editor should know that it's a bad idea to let the `...:` if one can't copy past afterward.